# Convergence of $\sum_{a \in \mathbb Z^2} \left(1+ \frac{|(z_1+a_1)(z_2+a_2)+B|^2}{4y_1y_2 B}\right)^{-s}$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence

Let
$$\mathbb H := \{ z=x+iy \in \mathbb C : y>0 \}$$
be the upper half plane.
For $B>0$ and $s \in \mathbb C$ we define the $\mathbb Z^2$ periodic function
$$H_s^B : \mathbb H^2 \to \mathbb R,\quad H_s^B(z) := \sum_{a \in \mathbb Z^2} \left(1+ \frac{|(z_1+a_1)(z_2+a_2)+B|^2}{4y_1y_2 B}\right)^{-s}$$
if it converges (here $y_i := \Im(z_i)$).

**Question 1:** For which $s\in \mathbb C$ does $H_s^B$ converge?

**My almost proof:** I think the condition is $\Re(s)>1/2$ because for $\Re(s)>1/2$ the integral
$$I_s^B(y):=\int_{\mathbb R^2} \left(1+ \frac{|z_1z_2+B|^2}{4y_1y_2 B}\right)^{-s} dx_1dx_2$$
converges (I actually computed it). By Fubini–Tonelli we have
$$\int_{[0,1]^2} H_s^B (z)dx_1dx_2 = I_s^B(y),$$
hence this implies the convergence of $H_s^B (z)$ for almost all $x_1,x_2 \in \mathbb R$. But of course I want to get it for all values.

**Special case $s=1$:**

For $s=1$ for example $I_1^B(y)$ is given by
$$I_1^B(y) = 4 \pi^2 B \sqrt{ \frac{y_1y_2}{y_1y_2+B}}.$$
So for fixed $y$ you see that we have
$$\lim _{B \to \infty} I_1^B(y) = \infty.$$

**Question 2:** How can the last limit be true even though each term in the sum $H_s^B(z)$ goes to zero for large $B$?